# Importing a class in matlab

Tags: matlab, oop, import, package

Pretty new to matlab. I want to have a class, which does some calculation. I want to import this class in another class( not instantiate). and use the functions as default functions.

[This](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/import.html) did not help me much. Can we import a user defined class/functions?

Answer (score 1):

So you have a class `calculationClass`, and you want to create another class `otherClass` that can access the calculations provided by `calculationClass`

One way that works if the calculations are either normal or static methods would be to subclass `calculationClass`, i.e. start your class definition with

```
classdef otherClass < calculationClass
[some code here]
end
```

This way, all methods of `calculationClass` immediately become available to `otherClass`. Note that if `calculationClass` has a nonempty constructor, the subclass will call the constructor as `this = this@calculationClass`.

If the calculations are static methods only, you can, alternatively, access those calculations as `calculationClass.someCalculation(inputArguments)`, or create a package and use `import`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I do understand the concept of inheritance. But i want to import the class.

Comment: @user5603723: can you say what functionality you need? Or why using static calls, or creating a package and using import doesn't do the trick?

Comment: @user5603723 The reason why Jonas does not know what you tries to accomplish is likely that import is supposed to work. Are the functions/members you tries to import declared private?

Comment: @Jonas . I am getting stuck at creating packages. the functions/members are all global. I kinda have the habit of never making my members private. I did not understand how to create a package of my class. but i found something in the internet which i don't think is the solution. But anyway, i went to file->setpath. added the file i wanted to import there. and i could just use the functions as default functions without creating an object

Comment: @patrik, pls check my answer above as i could not quote both of you in 1 reply.

Comment: @user5603723 this is how it is supposed to work. A function can not be used if it is not included in the Matlab path (which is like a workspace). I suspected as much but I was not sure. Import is actually not needed unless you have a package (which you seems not to). Further a package is only needed in case you want to modularize your code or if you have many classes/functions having the same name. You can also use the function `addpath` if you not want to add the paths permanently. In that you should have a setpath function which can be called first.

Comment: But it still doesn't work. says 'Undefined function '____' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: @user5603723: `which('yourClassName')` should show where Matlab finds the class on the path. If the output is empty, you need to make sure to update Matlab's path